# For loop, if a condition is met, stop searching, increase the index and start the loop again

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am trying to search though the columns on a 2D array/matrix (of Boolean values) to find the column that is all false, then return the index of that column.

```
   public int top() {       
       for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {     
               System.out.println("index i: "+ i+" index j:"+j);                
               if (matrix[i][j]==true) {
                   j++;
               }
           }
           return j;
      }
      System.out.println("failed");
      return -1;
   }
```

I want to break out of the nested For loops when a "true" value is detected, and start the search again at the top of the next column. Right now, when a true value is detected, the column is incremented and it continues searching the next column where the last left off- not the beginning as I'd like.

Is there any way to detect something in a for loop, change the index, then restart the search?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `break;` instead of `j++` that will break nested if and outer if will be incremented anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to only loop if `matrix[i][j]` is false. Then after checking a column, if it got to the end return the column index.

```java
public int top() {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { 
        int i = 0;
        while(i < size && !matrix[i][j]){
            System.out.println("index i: "+ i+" index j:"+j);
            i++;
        }
        if(i == size){
            return j;
        }
     }
     System.out.println("failed");
     return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `continue` and named loops for this purpose.

Notice how each loop is named with a self-explained name, making it easy to write the required algorithm

```
public int top() {
    COLUMNS_LOOP:
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        ROWS_LOOP:
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("index i: " + i + " index j:" + j);
            if (matrix[i][j]) {
                continue COLUMNS_LOOP;
            }
        }
        return j;
    }
    System.out.println("failed");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

public int top() {

```
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
           boolean failed = false;
           for (int i = 0; i < size && !failed; i++) {      
               System.out.println("index i: "+ i+" index j:"+j);
                if (matrix[i][j]) {
                     failed = true;
                }
            }
            
            if (!failed) {
                return j;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("failed");
    return -1;
    }
```

We are setting "failed" to tru in case we got 1 "true" in a column.
Then, our inner for loop will stop to processed.

In case we didn't find "true" value, we will iterate all column, and then (because "failed" is false) we will return the first column that was all false